# Calculate average monthly mileage

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of fleet vehicles that I'm attempting to calculate the average monthly and yearly mileage of.

For example, vehicle 1970 was manufactured in 2015, and has a current odometer of 105,341. That means the truck is 2 years or 24 months old. So the yearly average is 52,670 miles and the monthly average is 4,389.

I'm selecting the vehicle number, year of mfg., and the current odometer reading.

The field  M.ManufacturerYear is data type int and O.MeterLevel is data type varchar

How would I write the calculated fields to return the monthly and yearly average for each vehicle in the list?

Comment: Why is `MeterLevel` varchar and not numeric?

Comment: The idea of using just a year means the values will skew depending on the time of year of the odometer reading.

Comment: What have you tried? Because outside of the obvious issue SqlZim mentioned, what you're trying to achieve doesn't seem like it requires anything more than dividing your meterlevel by (year(getdate()) - manufactureryear)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an alternative of calculating the actual number of months and then annualizing (or normalizing) the results.

In the example below, Vehicle 2020 is only 7 months old, but the annualized mileage is greater than Vehicle 1970

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Vehicle] varchar(50),ManufacturerYear int,[Odometer] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1970,2015,105341)
,(2020,2017,25253)

Select *
      ,NbrMonths   = datediff(month,left(ManufacturerYear,4) +'0101',GetDate()) 
      ,PerMonth    =  [Odometer] / datediff(month,left(ManufacturerYear,4) +'0101',GetDate()) 
      ,Annualized  = ([Odometer] / datediff(month,left(ManufacturerYear,4) +'0101',GetDate()) ) * 12
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Here is a sample of the output after adding those 3 calculated fields. http://imgur.com/RvENX45

Comment: @SamStubbs Do those results satisfy your requirements?  If so, well done.

Comment: can you help me understand the part of the query that is adding '0101'?

Comment: @SamStubbs This is to convert the year into a date.  The implicit conversion will accept yyyymmdd or 20150101

Answer (score 0):

The below sample code is for similar scenario in MS SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE #Vehicle
(
VehicldId int,
YearOfManufacture smallint,
TotalMiles int,
AverageYearlyMiles AS TotalMiles / (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YearOfManufacture),
AverageMonthlyMiles AS TotalMiles / ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - YearOfManufacture) * 12 + MONTH(GETDATE()))
)



insert into #Vehicle(VehicldId,YearOfManufacture,TotalMiles) 
values ( 1970,2015,105400)

SELECT * FROM #Vehicle
```